# PowerBi Measure with Variables help requested

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am struggeling with a measure to calculate the average of each 2 values.

The problem is the "VAR MyIndex" (or more likely my lack of DAX skills) .
If I create a table with "VAR MyTable" and add a column with "VAR MyIndex" and "VAR __result". I get the expected output in a table.

An approach with rolling average doesnt work, as there are missing dates between the values.

What I created so far is a measure like this:

```
RollingAvg =

VAR MyTable =          
SUMMARIZE ( Table1, 
             Table1[Datum],
             "index", RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Table1),Table1[Datum],,ASC), 
             "AVG" , [myMeasure]) 

VAR MyIndex =  MyTable,[index]  --- This variable fails due to wrong syntax

VAR __result  =      CALCULATE(AVERAGE([AVG]),
                        FILTER(MyTable, 
                            [index] > MyIndex -2 && 
                            [index] <= MyIndex     ))
RETURN
__result
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

This is a table I can create and add a column with the xpected result.

[creating the expected result in a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/331ff.png)

So I want this rolling average calculation in a measure to be dynamic.

This is the mesaure i created:

```
AVG = 

VAR fest       = AVERAGE(Table1[FEST])
VAR avg_all    = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[FCI]), 
                                    FILTER(ALLSELECTED(Table1), 
                                        Table1[MATERIAL] = MAX (Table1[MATERIAL] &&
                                        Table1[PLANT] = MAX (Tabele1[PLANT] )) ))
                                        
VAR mwtr       = CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(Table1,Table1[FCI] - avg_all), Table1[FCI] <> BLANK()) 

VAR result     = mwtr + avg_all - fest

RETURN
result
```

FOr this I need the rolling Average - not by date - but row by row.

Comment: How do you want to design my index variable ? An aggregate function is required? MAX or MIN() ? Try this: MAXX(MyTable, [index]) or MINX(MyTable, [index])?

Comment: I changed the measure like this:RollingAvg =
VAR MyTable =  
SUMMARIZE ( Table1, 
             Table1[Datum],
             "index", RANKX(ALLSELECTED(Table1),Table1[Datum],,ASC), 
             "AVG" , [myMeasure]) 

VAR MyIndex =  MINX(MyTable,[index])  --- This variable fails due to wrong syntax

VAR __result  =      CALCULATE(AVERAGEX(MyTable,[AVG]),
                        FILTER(MyTable, 
                            [index] > MyIndex -2 && 
                            [index] <= MyIndex     ))
RETURN
__result

But this gives me the same result as mymeasure for each row.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the build-in **Quick measure** for *Rolling average*?
But as with any kind of DAX time-intelligence you need a separate Date table.

If you need more help you have to provide sample data in copyable markdown format.

Comment: Hi Peter, I have a separate date table. But all attempts with the build in QuickMeasure failed due to non-continuous dates.

Comment: But you can easily create a continuous date table with CALENDARAUTO() and relate it to your other table.

Comment: And if I have only values for the 1st and the 4th of a month, the QuickMeasure wont average them with "2 DAY" rolling.  But this is what I need. At least is my experience with the QuickMeasure.